# Make certain characters in an Excel cell subscript Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, subscript

I'm trying to write a Python script that takes the text in a cell of an Excel spreadsheet, and makes certain characters subscript or superscript.  I was using OpenPyxl, but I've read that it doesn't allow modifications smaller than a whole cell, so I'm open to using a different package if necessary.

For reference, I need the 2 characters after the "T" in each cell to be a subscript.  So take the string "T12+0.10", or "<(T12+17.00"and format it in place so that the "12" is a subscript, as in the image below.

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
style = XFStyle()
style.font = fnt
style.borders = borders
substyle = fnt.ESCAPEMENT_SUBSCRIPT
superstyle = fnt.ESCAPEMENT_SUPERSCRIPT


def compare(contents):
    s = ""
    for i in contents:
        nextchar=contents[i+1].value
        if i.value.contains ("T"):
            j = i + 1, substyle
            s += str(s + j)
        else:
            s += str(i)

wb = op.load_workbook("file_name.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet3"]
for row in ws.iter_rows("C{}:C{}".format(ws.min_row, ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        contents = cell.value
        compare(contents)
```

Comment: xlwt is for the earlier excel file format .xls files.

Comment: Openpyxl is capable of applying subscript to the whole cell not individual characters in the cell. Splitting the cell contents so the required characters are in a separate cell and applying subscript to that cell will work but recombining into a single cell will loose the subscript formatting. Xlsxwriter **can** do individual characters within the cell but as you are probably aware you cannot edit an existing excel file so it would mean creating a new sheet/book to do this.

Comment: The ability to do this **will** be availaible in openpyxl 3.1. However, Excel really is unsuitable for this kind of thing and you should avoid it when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Xlwings you can do it this way, working on the assumption that where there is a 'T' in the cell contents the next two chars are subscripted.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')
for x in range(1, 6): 
    contents = ws.range(1, x).value 
    if 'T' in contents: # Checks for T in the cell contents
        i = contents.index('T')+1
        ws.range(1, x).characters[i:i+2].api.Font.Subscript = True

wb.save()
wb.close()
```

As an example this changes the following cells A1:E1 from

```
T12+0.10    <(T12+17.00 A12+1.11    A+0.10T12   B14+111
```

to

[image]

[xlwings](/questions/tagged/xlwings)